# Hamiltonian paths in subgraphs of rectangular lattice graphs

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, algorithms, reference-request

Is following decision problem NP-hard / NP-complete:

1. Having vertex-induced subgraph of rectangular lattice graph determine if any Hamiltonian path exists
2. Having vertex-induced subgraph of rectangular lattice graph determine if exists Hamiltonian path starting at given point (path end can be anywhere)

Please give me some references.

Comment: Since it is NP-complete to find a Hamiltonian path in a cubic planar graph (Garey and Johnson, 1970s, http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/pub.html), I think this is NP-complete.

Comment: Is it obvious that cublic planar graph is a vertex-induced subgraph of rectangular lattice graph?

Comment: 1. NP-complete, answer is here: http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/daver/Pubs/MyPDF/superThin.pdf

2. NP-complete by polyminal reduction to problem 1 - just check Hamiltonian path for every vertex

Comment: The idea I had was that you should be able to lengthen the edges and embed any cubic graph into the lattice in a way which preserves Hamiltonian paths and only expands the graph a polynomial amount. It's not obvious to me that this is possible, and I haven't filled in the details, but this is not the type of problem where I think you need a super-polynomial expansion. By the way, it's fine to post an answer to your own question. 

Comment: I have some funny idea:
1. Draw cubic planar graph on white piece of paper with black pen, so that there are no edge intersections.
2. Take a photo with digital camera.

Now all pixels in photo form square lattice, black pixels are verteices of lattice subgraph. With correct lens scaling this would produce good embedding ;)

Comment: That procedure works in many examples, but it takes some work to try to make it apply to all planar cubic graphs. 
You don't start with straight edges. The Koebe-Andreev-Thurston theorem says there are good embeddings, but perhaps that's overkill. 

Comment: @DouglasZare: Doesn't his method work? Any planar graph can be drawn with straight edges, but even without that fact we could still do it with curved edges, since every vertex has degree only 3. And I think the number of vertices needed in the rectangular graph would be at most $O(n^4)$.

Comment: @user21820: Do you disagree with my statement that some work needs to be done? What is your proof of the $O(n^4)$ statement, and wouldn't that count as work?

Comment: @DouglasZare: Of course I agree that work has to be done, but I was wondering why you said earlier that it was not obvious to you that it is possible, and that we might need a super-polynomial expansion. My reason for $O(n^4)$ is that I'm very sure we only need a grid distance of $O(n)$ between any two coordinates.

Comment: @user21820: There are some problems in higher dimensions where fitting a combinatorial structure into a grid can take a super-polynomial amount of expansions, even though it seems intuitive that it should be easy. See the animal problem and the word problem for groups. Again, I don't think this is the type of problem where you need a super-polynomial expansion but it has to be worked out, and I gave an argument for how you might simplify a graph using the Koebe-Andreev-Thurston theorem. If you think it is obvious without this type of simplification, are you sure your intuition is solid?

Comment: @DouglasZare: Here is a sketch of what I have in mind. For each vertex one by one, put a small circle around it such that the circle's bounding box lies completely to one side of every existing circle or other vertex. Define the grid using coordinates of all the circles' bounding boxes and refine the grid by a factor of $3n$. For each vertex use three appropriate grid points on its circle's bounding box. Now construct each edge one by one, each using at most two directions and greedily but passing on the correct side of each other vertex.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Well not exactly do each edge one by one. We should construct all the 'paths' first and see which ones must pass through which unrefined grid cell. The refinement should guarantee that there is enough space for all the paths. Anyway I agree that my intuition is often faulty, and my refinement factor may be off, but I think this method will succeed in this case. =)